# Address Book Person View in OS x not working after setHidden to Yes. Why?

Tags: macos, abaddressbook, abperson

I am using AB Person View in OS x application , it is working fine , but when i hide it like

```
[self.abpersonView setHidden:YES];
```

and show it again by calling

[self.abPersonView setHidden:NO];

it appears but its not even scrollable and clickable.

I am unable to understand this behavior. kindly assist me.

Comment: Which OS X? Since 10.10.5 there have been huge changes introducing new bugs in ABPersonView. They want you to use ContactsUI framework

Comment: Can you test on 10.10? I think the underlaying changes (ABPersonView is layered now) broke it.

Comment: Thanks @MarekH can you please tell me how to add more fields to ABPersonView? like suffix, prefix , phonetic first name e.t.c while creating a new contact Programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @Marek H I have found the answer. you should hide the ABPersonView like

```
[self.abpersonView.layer setHidden:YES];
```

and unhide it like

```
[self.abpersonView.layer setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: Just add that this change happened since El Cap